# single view for multiple term Image slideshow

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have created a taxonomy vocabulary as a product and created a taxonomy term as a collection, collection1 and so on. In collection i have an option to add multiple images once if i add, it will display in their respective collection term page and same process has been followed for Remaining taxonomy terms.

While click on the collection term page it will need to show particular images as a slideshow and same as it is for other collections taxonomy terms also.

Now I need single view to display the images as a slideshow. I can able to bring out the particular images of the taxonomy terms using contextual filter(using TermID) option in view, whereas i would like to show those images as slideshow. Is it possible to do.